# module_invoke_all not returning all modules

Tags: drupal, hook

I'm creating a module wich provides a separate node overview page for each content type.
My problem lies in trying to recreate the node operations dropdown.

In the node module this is done by calling the module_invoke_all function with the 'node_operations' hook.
This returns an array of all modules that implement the 'node_operations' hook.
In my case the following two modules: 'node' and 'nodewords'.

When I call module_invoke_all('node_operations') in my module, it returns only the 'nodewords' module, not the 'node' module.
This is because the 'node_node_operations' function does not exist.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the hook is in node.admin.inc, which is not automatically included. See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.admin.inc/function/node_node_operations/7

This is imho a bug, you should look if there already is an issue and if not, create a new one.

Anyway, as a workaround, you can include the node.admin.inc file like this before calling the hook:

```
<?php
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.admin');
?>
```

(Yeah, weird syntax ;))

Comment: This works. Thx.
Good to know that only hooks in the .module file are automatically included.

Comment: Drupal 7 initially contained a function registry that automatically parsed all files and stored which functions are stored where. But that was removed again because it had too many downsides, like actually being slower when using APC.